# How do I Click on all the selected links from the web page and then come back to the landing page and click the next link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have just started with selenium. Now I have all the links that I want to click.This links lead me to a Page that I want to **scrape**. When the driver click on the first link it works perfectly fine but on second link click I get the message as :

`Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

```py
def view_All_pages(driver , file_object):
    #All the Links that i want to click
    list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='@ClassName']")
    for link in list_of_links:
        time.sleep(10)
        link.click()  #Getting the error here
        scraping_Normal_page(driver , file_object)
        driver.back()
```

I want to **scrape** the the page and come back to the opening page and then click on to the next link. Help will be appreciated

Comment: @orde Thank you this was useful and worked for me as well. But I think it is not the best way

Answer (score 0):

Stale element Reference Exception is thrown when reference to an (already found and saved) element changes. In your case you navigate to a new page but your list contains saved elements that are part of the parent page. So when you navigate back the elements in the list becomes stale.

This can be solved by re-initializing the element / list on navigating pack from the **scraped** web page. You have to change the iteration over the list to iterate over index.

```
def view_All_pages(driver , file_object):
    #All the Links that i want to click
    list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='@ClassName']")
    length_of_list  = len(list_of_links)
    # Iterate over the list based on index
    i = 0
    while i < len(length_of_list):
        time.sleep(10)
        list_of_links.index(i).click()
        scraping_Normal_page(driver , file_object)
        driver.back()
        i += 1
        # Reinitialize the list of elements again
        list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='@ClassName']")
```

Comment: Sorry but this did not work for me

Comment: What error are you getting now ?